# Android, detect open cursors in whole project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cursor

How to find cursors that are not closed in whole project that may cause memory leaks and other problems since Android lint warns them now?

Comment: add log on everywhere you open and close a cursor. check if the open and close present in pair in you logcat

Comment: My app has more than 150 classes and many places to use cursor, the first way I think about was search key word `cursor` and then check it, but it is too slow to do so. Thanks.

Comment: root a device, hook the cursor opening API with `xposed` to log out

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I found the way!

from top menu: `Analyze`>`Inspect code` then `whole project` and `OK`

Now wait till `Android studio` finds `lint` problems in your app, then go to the below item and check if the not recycled item is `Cursor`, also you can use it for other resources that are open but not closed!

`Android > Lint > Performance`
then `Missing recycle() calls`